# How can i use custom font to my theme in magento?

Tags: magento, css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to develop a magento theme, i am going well with every other thing, except one, i want to use custom font in my magento theme as per my client requirement, the font is "eurostilebold", i tried as i do it core php, like i putted the font files in font folder and placed the font folder into

> D:\xampp\htdocs\clothing_site\skin\frontend\default\gwcc\

this directory. 
Now i am using that font family in my css and calling like that :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'eurostile_extended_2regular';
src: url('fonts/eurostile_extended_2-webfont.eot');
```

All i want to know how to use any custom downloaded font family in magento, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would like to use Google web fonts, read this article: https://www.themes-mgnto.com/blog/post/view/identifier/google-fonts-api-magento-commerce/

Answer (score 2):

To use a custom font on your website you have 3 options.

1. Use open-source and free online fonts like google fonts and font squirrel, please search free web font on google. I personally use open sans and other google fonts a lot in my designs.
2. Use some paid font service. (I never used this so no experience)
3. Embed your local font on your website. here is how:

You'll need to convert your font to different formats like .eot, .svg, .ttf, .woff as different browsers support different formats. http://screencast.com/t/0KV17zkSri Then, add those fonts in your CSS like this: http://screencast.com/t/ypgKHV7lSm Now, use a font like this: http://screencast.com/t/NheSnxPCE1SN

there are several services available online that converts a given format to all other required like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. If these services blacklist your font then try to search a specific format like "ttf to eot" and you ll find some other service there.

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Adobe Garamond Regular';

    src: url('../fonts/Adobe Garamond Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Adobe Garamond Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Adobe Garamond Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.otf') format('otf'),
         url('../fonts/Adobe Garamond Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Adobe Garamond Regular.svg#Adobe Garamond Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body{  font-family:'Adobe Garamond Regular';  } //added to code
```

Comment: Plus to you for not giving standard Google Fonts when OP did NOT ask for Google Font Solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference you webfont in other css files :

```
body{
    font-family:"eurostile_extended_2regular",Arial, ... , ;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: You missed a lot of details here. You have to at least include the source of the web font. (p.s. you trust w3schools? read w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert my font via [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or another service.

This will make you a zip folder with everything you need, both the font files and the css.

Then just include the css and now you can use it in your css like this, on any element you want.

```
html {
    font-family: "eurostile", OtherFallbackFont;
}
```

or for just headers:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "eurostile", OtherFallbackFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just install this Magento extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/googlefonts.html

It will let you choose the desired font from the backend and install the font correctly all by itself. You then just have to access it via CSS.

Comment: EUR29 for just adding Google Fonts? Nope. Just add 1 line in template file doesn't worth that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download your font, then upload it to skin/frontend/default/your_theme/fonts, and then call it in your @font-face part of your css script, which is located at: skin/frontend/default/your_theme/css/styles_your_layout.css

Answer (score 0):

In case you make your own theme, in your theme's `local.xml` (which should be place at `app/design/frontend/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/{YOUR_THEME}/layout/`), it may look like (yours may be different than below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/base.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Add the following link in `<reference name="head">` before the `addCss` line to ensure it's loaded before the `base.css`:

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400,700</href></action>
```

which becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400,700</href></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/base.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Upload back to your theme's folder. Clear cache & reload the page, you'll see the Google Fonts CSS is added to HTML's head.

To use the Google Web Font (slightly off-topic to this question), you can apply the font to any CSS selector you want. For example:

```
p {
  font-family: Cardo, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the absolute easiest way is to go to System->Configuration

There from the General group go to Design and on the HTML Head section use the Misc Scripts to paste something like this:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style> body {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !Important;}</style>
```

Where the link is for the desired google font (why would you need any other?)