# How to add new font to custom magento theme?

Tags: css, magento, fonts

I tried to add new font to my custom magento theme which not include in fonts. But it not work.

This is the CSS i used.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font-one;
    src: url(../../CoCo/magento/skin/frontend/default/master/fonts/Pacifico.ttf);
}

.font-one{
font-family: font-one;
color:#b02c1d;
}
```

I put font file in skin mytheme folder. and this is the way i added it.

```
<h3 class="top font-one">-- New --</h3>
```

Can anyone help me to correct this matter?

Comment: have you checked weather your font file gets added or not?

Comment: you should check using firebug if path of Pacifico.ttf is correct or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15571449/2879463 Its been already asked and i think you `url()` is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i use custom font to my theme in magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570860/how-can-i-use-custom-font-to-my-theme-in-magento)

Comment: Kawinesh SK no it was not the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried to add new font to my custom magento theme

You should include the `.ttf` file in your template folder.  Like:

```
skin/frontend/default/{theme_name}
```

From your question observation, it seems your custom theme name is "master".

The url you mentioned for font-face declaration is:

```
../../CoCo/magento/skin/frontend/default/master/fonts/Pacifico.ttf
```

I am sure that the url you mentioned to declare the `font-face` is wrong as it is going outside the project folder.

Let me explain you with an example on how to set a url in this case:

For just explanation, I am assuming the following directory to your {custom_theme} for skin.

```
skin/frontend/default
    --> {custom_theme_name}     #which is 'master', I think
         --> fonts
             --> Pacifico.ttf
         --> CSS
             --> main.css
```

For example, If you are declaring the new font-face in `main.css` then it should be something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: font-one;
    src: url(../fonts/Pacifico.ttf);  /* check this */
}
```